# Android ICS FFMPEG scale video not working

Tags: android, process, ffmpeg

I am using [Guardian Project Android Java FFMPEG](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java) library to resize videos. Current code which is working on `android 5.0.1 / 5.1.0 / 4.4.4` :

```
    File fileTmp = getCacheDir();
    FfmpegController fc = null;
    try {
        fc = new FfmpegController(this, fileTmp);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Movies/nexus.mp4";
    final String outPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Movies/test.mp4";
    final Clip out = new Clip(path);
    try {
        if (fc != null) {
            fc.convert(out, outPath, new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {
                @Override
                public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
                    Log.e("", "SHELL OUT: " + shellLine);
                }

                @Override
                public void processComplete(int exitValue) {
                    Log.e("", "PROCESS COMPLETE: " + exitValue);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Using this code on Android 4.0.4 (Ice Cream Sandwich) doesn't do anything. While testing on other devices `exitValue` in `processComplete` is always equal to `0`, but on ICS it's `11`. Here is the output in LogCat:

```
SHELL OUT: /data/data/org.hardartcore.ffmpeg/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -i /mnt/sdcard/Movies/NEXUS.mp4 -ab 160k -r ntsc-film -vf scale=568:320 -strict -2 /mnt/sdcard/Movies/Test.mp4
PROCESS COMPLETE: 11
```

I don't think it's something from ffmpeg, more like a problem when the library is trying to execute ffmpeg executable from raw folder in internal memory, but I can't see any logs or errors which indicate that too.

So my question is, if there is any mistake which I am doing using / running this code or something which can prevent ffmpeg executable from running on old devices with Android ICS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you enable verbose log level ?

Comment: @ben75 you mean if I enabled debugging and logs for app / device or something about ffmpeg which I don't know?

Comment: Yes I speak about logcat log level

Comment: Yes, everything is enabled, I see all other logs before and after loading application..but there is nothing which indicates that there is some kind of error during executing commands using ffmpeg executable.

Comment: It is strange that you don't see any logs between first 'SHELL OUT' and 'PROCESS COMPLETE'. Normally, all shell output must be forwarded to logcat (thanks to FFMpegController.StreamGobbler), unless there is an exception while reading process error/output stream. Suggestion : put a breakpoint in FFMPEGController.StreamGobbler, line 1345 (https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/blob/master/src/org/ffmpeg/android/FfmpegController.java#L1345) to check if this line is reached or not.

Comment: Nope, there is no exception thrown, the code reach run part, but `br.readLine()` return `null`.

Comment: Try this (you must recompile FfmpegController) : add `-loglevel debug` to the command line. i.e. in FfmegController.java line 798 : insert those lines : `cmd.add("-loglevel"); cmd.add("debug");` and look at the output. You should get far more information.

Comment: @ben75 nope, still doesn't have any extra output between shellOut and processComplete.

Comment: My last guess: your device running 4.0.4 is an x86 and ffmpeg lib are for armeabi architecture (or other similar problem regarding target architecture of the libraries vs actual architecture of your device)

Comment: My device which runs ICS is ARMv7 and as far as I know ffmpeg and this build support that.

Comment: i am using same library and found same problem.

Comment: I find out what is the problem and will post an answer after a few minutes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lots of tests and building `ffmpeg` for Android I discovered that using `ffmpeg` executable build without `PIE support` (which is required by `Android Lollipop`) on `Android 4.0 / 4.0.3 / 4.0.4` works like a charm.

So if you have the same problem, try to test with `ffmpeg` build which doesn't include `PIE support` and see if it will work. In my case that did the trick.